# CDN - find the source IP

Tags: ip, cdn

I want to communicate directly with website using CDN (Akamai, CloudFlare, etc.)

Anyone knows if is it possible to find the IP address of websites using Akamai? or CloudFlare?

I have tried to ping to example.com without 'www' prefix and I get IP address that not belongs to Akamai. But I donwt sure what is this IP.
I tried to open HTTP communication with this IP, but I get various results for thee various websites: some of them redirect me to the Akamai server, others give me '404 Not Found' error, etc.

what is this IP?

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? Why do you want to do whatever it is you try?

Comment: I want to understand what is this IP address

Comment: This Q really looks like an offtopic, since business case for such thing is not clear and you failed to provide one when asked. Smells blackhat ... Unfortunate first question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

That is usually one of the points of deploying CDN. Hiding the actual data source, so it is not as easy to be (D)DoSed.